# Tinymce and uploading local pictures

Tags: images, uploads, tinymce

I would like to extend the capabilities of the wordpress editor while keeping the option of uploading local pictures (in the simplest way possible:upload => insert).

I found a plugin which seems to be simple and nice - "JBimages" - but there are others too.
All of them are supposed to be dropped in the "plugins" folder of TinyMCE.

The thing is I can't find any version of the original tinyMCE (the one having the "plugins" folder).
Wherever I go I find the "Advanced Tinymce" or the "Ultimate Tinymce" but not the original one.
And none of these Tinymce's have a folder called "plugins" where I can drop the "JBimages" extension (or any other one).

Just to be sure, I went to the TMCE website and took an old version of the plugin but it doesn't seem to work within wordpress 3.x

What can I do to add this "upload picture" functionality to a wordpress Tinymce plugin, whatever the version?
JBimages would be my first choice but if there is any free and simple solution out there which would achieve my purpose, I'll take it (as long as its straight forward and easy to use).